# Getting Cocos2d-x method completions in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I've been playing with Sublime Text 2 the last few days and was wondering if anyone out there has had any success getting Cocos2d-x method completions working yet? I've install Sublimeclang,but it doesn't work well.
There is my setting of Sublimeclang

```
{
"options":
[
    "-m32",
    "-w",
    "-fgnu-runtime",
    "-fms-extensions",
    "-nostdinc",
    "-D__GNUC__=4",
    "-D__GNUC_MINOR__=2",
    "-D__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__=1",
    "-D__GXX_ABI_VERSION__=1002",
    "-Di386=1",
    "-D__i386=1",
    "-D__i386__=1",
    "-DWIN32=1",
    "-D_WIN32=1",
    "-D__WIN32=1",
    "-D__WIN32__=1",
    "-DWINNT=1",
    "-D__WINNT=1",
    "-D__WINNT__=1",
    "-D_X86_=1",
    "-D__MSVCRT__=1",
    "-D__MINGW32__=1",
    "-D__STDC_VERSION__=201112L",
    //"-isystem", "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/",
    //"-isystem", "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1",
    "-isystem", "D:\\Developer\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.6.2\\include",
    "-isystem", "D:\\Developer\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.6.2\\include\\c++",
    "-isystem", "D:\\Developer\\mingw\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\4.6.2\\include\\c++\\mingw32",
    "-isystem", "D:\\Developer\\mingw\\include\\",
    "-DANDROID",
    "-isystem", "D:\\Developer\\android-ndk-r8e\\toolchains\\x86-4.6\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\lib\\gcc\\i686-linux-android\\4.6\\include",
    "-isystem", "D:\\Developer\\android-ndk-r8e",
    "-isystem", "D:\\Developer\\android-ndk-r8e\\sources\\cxx-stl\\gnu-libstdc++\\4.6\\include",
    "-isystem", "D:\\Developer\\android-ndk-r8e\\sources\\cxx-stl\\gnu-libstdc++\\4.6\\libs\\x86\\include",

    "-isystem", "D:/Developer/Cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4/cocos2dx",
    "-isystem", "D:/Developer/Cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4/cocos2dx/include",
    "-isystem", "D:/Developer/Cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4/cocos2dx/platform/android",
    "-isystem", "D:/Developer/Cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android",



    "-Wall",
    "-ferror-limit=0"
]
```

}

Unfortunately, the autocompletion only lists macro, no class and method.

Comment: For possible autocompletion options with Sublime I suggest study this article: http://opensourcehacker.com/2013/03/04/javascript-autocompletions-and-having-one-for-sublime-text-2/